# how to validate inputs in a child component (formik)

Tags: reactjs, formik

I generated Field in `CustomField` and call it in the `CustomForm` component. I want to validate each `Customefield` in itself with `validateAsync` but `validateAsync` is not working and meta. the `error` object is always empty.

this is my `CustomForm` component:

```
import { Field, Form, Formik, yupToFormErrors } from "formik";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CustomField from "./customeField";
import * as Yup from "yup";

class CustomForm extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ name1: "", name2: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        <Form>
          <CustomField name="name1" lable="name1"></CustomField>
          <CustomField name="name2" lable="name2"></CustomField>
          <button type="submit">send</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    );
  }
}
export default CustomForm;
```

and this is my `CustomField` component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Field, Form, Formik, useField, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const CustomField = ({ lable, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  const validateAsync = () =>
    Yup.object({
      name1: Yup.string().required("error"),
    });
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={props.id || props.name}>{lable}</label>
      <Field validate={validateAsync} {...field} {...props} />
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="error"></div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CustomField;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two problems in your code, the first one is how you use the `Yup` for validation and the second problem is about that `validateAsync` function, as [Formik doc](https://formik.org/docs/api/field#validate) mentions you have to get input value from the first argument and as result, you can return undefined (which means there is no error) or a string (error message), BTW it's also possible to return a promise that indicates is input value valid or not.

here is how you can go with this case:

```
const CustomField = ({ label, name }: CustomFieldProps) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField({ name });

  const validate = (x: string) => {
    const error_msg = "Error!!!";
    try {
      Yup.string().required(error_msg).validateSync(x).toString();
    } catch (error) {
      return error_msg;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Field validate={validate} {...field} />
      {meta.touched && meta.error && <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

p.s: here is the link of a working sample sandbox if you need a playground:

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-field-validate-rx3snh?file=/src/App.tsx:173-650